# do.call skip error and continue processing

Tags: r

After a for loop I create 4 dataframes (`data1, data2,data3,data4`), i want to rbind all of them. 
I tried:

```
do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("data", 1:4)))
```

but sometimes, the `for` loop gives me only 3 of them, for example: `data1, data2, data4`.

it seems that `do.call` doesn't know how to handle this issue.

How could I do to still have an `rbind` of `data1, data2, data4`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all your objects from the global environment (via `ls()`) and use `grep` to get the ones that follow the pattern you need, i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, mget(grep('data[0-9]+', ls(), value = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check if dataframe `exists` in the environment and `mget` only those.

```
data_names <- paste0("data", 1:4)
do.call(rbind, mget(data_names[sapply(data_names, exists)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching mechanism in `ls` to identify your objects, as `mget` takes character vector of object names and `pattern` argument in `ls` can use regular expression, which is more flexible than generating object names via `paste`.

```
data_cars_one <- mtcars
data_cars_two <- mtcars

library(tidyverse)
res_all <- bind_rows(mget(x = ls(pattern = "^data")))
```

Concerning the binding, I've used `bind_rows` just as an alternative to `do.call` and `Reduce` solutions.